# Reading $_GET after clicking the href image. How to display other data?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
include ('adoption_1.php');

if(isset($_GET['animal_ID'])){
    $aID = intval($_GET['animal_ID']);

    $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM adoption where a_id = ?, Abreed= ?, AAnimalName= ?");
    $result->bind_param('iss', $aID, $Abreed, $AAnimalName);
    $result->execute();

    $AAnimalName = ($_GET['AAnimalName']);
    $Abreed = ($_GET['Abreed']);

    echo $aID. $Abreed. $AAnimalName;

}else{

    echo "animal id not set";
    //exit or redirect back
}

?>
```

[image: LINKING IMAGE]

I want to show more information of each pet shown in the image. New to prepared statements. I guess i did something wrong with the query. $aID is working on the display when clicked. How to show other information such as `$AAnimalName` and `$Abreed`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks for correcting the syntax mr. Tried `where a_id = ?` works fine for me but still i have to explore more on how to show infos.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT * FROM adoption where a_id = ?, Abreed= ?, AAnimalName= ?` is incorrect syntax.

RTM's

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/where-optimizations.html

The `WHERE` clause uses `AND` - `OR` as separators, not commas as does `UPDATE`.

Comment: @Powerballs Right on ;-)

Comment: The information shown/displayed is not the information of the `aID` that was clicked.

Comment: Additional prob. :(

Comment: @Powerballs then your query may have failed you. Check for errors via PHP's error reporting and `mysqli_error($conn)` on the query.

Comment: No errors but doesn't change the name and breed when clicked. Just the id. Thanks btw!!

Comment: @Powerballs place `$AAnimalName = ($_GET['AAnimalName']);
    $Abreed = ($_GET['Abreed']);` under `$aID = intval($_GET['animal_ID']);` and make sure the parameters you use in the link for it matches and in lettercase.

Comment: I did it earlier but it says undefined index. Fixing.. @Fred-ii-

Comment: @Powerballs You need to use a conditional statement then around all your variables/GET arrays. Using `isset()` for all of those.

Comment: This is what I did and it went to else statement `if(isset($_GET['animal_ID'], $_GET['AAnimalName'], $_GET['Abreed']))`